# Using Google Mock with boost::bind

Tags: c++, boost, bind, googletest, googlemock

I have a class whose constructor takes a Boost function, and I'd like to test it with Google Mock. The following code shows a sample class and my attempt to test it:

MyClass.h:

```
#include <boost/function.hpp>
class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass(boost::function<void()> callback);
    void callCallback();
private:
    boost::function<void()> m_callback;
};
```

MyClassTest.cpp:

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include <gmock/gmock.h>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include "MyClass.h"
class CallbackMock
{
public:
    MOCK_METHOD0(callback, void());
};

TEST(MyClassShould, CallItsCallback)
{
    CallbackMock callbackMock;
    MyClass myClass(boost::bind(&CallbackMock::callback, callbackMock));
    EXPECT_CALL(callbackMock, callback()).Times(1);
    myClass.callCallback();
}
```

Attempting to compile MyClassTest.cpp in Visual Studio 2008 gives the following error:

> ...gmock/gmock-generated-function-mockers.h(76)
>   : error C2248:
>   'testing::internal::FunctionMockerBase::FunctionMockerBase'
>   : cannot access private member
>   declared in class
>   'testing::internal::FunctionMockerBase'
>   1>        with 1>        [ 1>
>   F=void (void) 1>        ] 1>
>   .../gmock-spec-builders.h(1656) : see
>   declaration of
>   'testing::internal::FunctionMockerBase::FunctionMockerBase'
>   1>        with 1>        [ 1>
>   F=void (void) 1>        ] 1>
>   This diagnostic occurred in the
>   compiler generated function
>   'testing::internal::FunctionMocker::FunctionMocker(const
>   testing::internal::FunctionMocker
>   &)' 1>        with 1>        [ 1>
>   Function=void (void) 1>        ]

The error stems from the line containing boost::bind. Replacing the mocked method with void callback(){} eliminates the compile error (but also eliminates the use of Google Mock, defeating the purpose). Is what I'm trying to do possible without modifying the tested class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this line is wrong:

`MyClass myClass(boost::bind(&CallbackMock::callback, callbackMock));`

The last parameter should be `&callbackMock`

Answer (score 17):

The reason is that Google Mock mocks are not copyable - that is by design. When you try to pass it into `boost::bind` by value, the compiler fails to generate the copy constructor. You should take the mock's address when passing it into `bind`:

```
MyClass myClass(boost::bind(&CallbackMock::callback, &callbackMock));
```

Comment: Thanks for the additional clarification.

Comment: This really should be the accepted answer. You just saved me a lot of time!!! Thanks Vlad!